Is there any way to connect springboot with AWS SNS to publish message without Access key and secret key?
I am in a situation where I lost access key & secret key but I want to connect SNS and SQS from a spring boot application which is later deployed on AWS Lambda. Is there any way to connect without credentials

I don't want to create New user because l am using my company provided AWS account

When writing a Lambda function that invokes AWS SNS, you do not need to provide access keys (i.e., an AWS Access Key and AWS Secret Key) in your Lambda function code. Instead, you can use an IAM execution role to grant the necessary permissions to your Lambda function.
The IAM execution role is an IAM role that you associate with your Lambda function. This role defines the set of permissions that the Lambda function can assume when it is executed. By granting the appropriate permissions to the IAM execution role, you can allow your Lambda function to interact with AWS SNS without the need for hard-coded access keys.
If you are using this Service within a Spring Boot app, and not a Lambda function, then you need to use keys.
